# Multiple users database connection pooling in JBoss AS/Wildfly

Tags: java, jboss, datasource, connection-pooling

I'm working on web application, that need access to postgresql database.

For some reason, i need to establish individual connection, for every authenticated user.

My current datasource setup looks like this:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/ds" pool-name="ds-pool" enabled="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.2:5432/springdb</connection-url>
                    <driver>postgresql-driver</driver>
                    <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>30</max-pool-size>                       
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>postgres</user-name>
                        <password>postgres</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
```

In java code i do this:

```
@Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/ds")
DataSource ds;
conn = ds.getConnection(username, password);
```

And here is the problem. Every getConnection call produce following WARN in jboss console:

```
> 14:07:48,665 WARN 
> [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (default
> task-11) IJ000612: Destroying connection that could not be
> successfully matched:
> org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@7de0e076[state=NORMAL
> managed
> connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@763ace0a
> connection handles=0 lastUse=1382422068665 trackByTx=false
> pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@36c78449
> mcp=SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool@64bdf0b7[pool=ds-pool]
> xaResource=LocalXAResourceImpl@ead2f2a[connectionListener=7de0e076
> connectionManager=26e60dae warned=false currentXid=null
> productName=PostgreSQL productVersion=9.3.3 jndiName=java:jboss/ds]
> txSync=null]
```

I've tried to add **allow-multiple-users** to **pool** configuration, but in jboss 7 i'm getting xml parse error, and in wildfly 8 it does nothing.

So is there any way to get multiple users connection pool in jboss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that I figured it out. So to enable multiple users in a connection pool, you need to add the following in the datasource definition:

```xml
<allow-multiple-users>true</allow-multiple-users>
```

instead of:

```xml
<allow-multiple-users/>
```

Wildfly 8.0.0